# Angular routing, load full (sub)project

Tags: angular, routes, project, angular-routing

I created a solution 'my-app' with a main project and a (sub)project 'app1':
[structure solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfZL0.png)

With ng-serve the project runs:
[my-app works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLAka.png)

With ng-serve --project app1 the (sub) project runs:
[app1 works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENh0h.png)

Then I have added routing to my-app, to reference to app1 (and app2):
[added routing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijjMF.png)

Running the my-app and navigate to the url works:
[routing works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lbh2P.png)

Now the module from app1 is loaded in my-app. But that's not what I want, I have created a separate project to load the full project and use the own index.html of app1.

Is it possible to route with localhost:4200/app1 to the full app1 project? So it loads the main.ts and the index.html from app1 in stead of my-app?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is indeed loading both apps.

Why:

- because you load the `SharedModule` of them in your main project.

What you are trying to achieve is to [lazy load](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules) the module according to the route.

For that, in the new version of Angular, we have a new syntax:

```
loadChildren: () => import('./app1/app1.module').then(m => m.App1Module) }
```

And that's it! No need to import your module.